# radio button binding in IList <model > mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I bind a radio button in mvc as my view is like this?

```
@model IList<CMM.Models.Question>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ques", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-3" }))
{

@foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
@Html.RadioButtonFor(item.QuestionId,item.QuestionId,item)//error in this line
@Html.RadioButtonFor(item.QuestionId,item.QuestionId,item)//error in this line
}
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

I want only 1 radio button will be checked for each row. and from data will be pass to my controller.My controller is like this.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IList<Question> sq)
        {          

            return View();
        }
```

How can i display radio button.I want 3 functions in radio.

```
1)different id's
2)different values
3)javascript func call onclick of radio button..
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Rather than "RadioButtonFor" try "RadioButton" instead.

Comment: Can u show your question model?

Comment: Have a look here it is covering your case: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6640157/2932724

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {


     @Html.RadioButtonFor( item => item .QuestionId, item.option1 )


     @Html.RadioButtonFor( item => item .QuestionId, item.option2)

    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

option1 and option2 are the options. and will be defined in model