# Edit multiple record in ASP.Net with three radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to implement student attendance application where instructor can give the student one of three status(Present, Absent, Unrecorded). After instructor login he can go to class and change each student status and save change
[image]

So simply I modify the https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859712/3254920

**Models**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Full Name ")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Student Status")]
    public int StudentStatus { get; set; }
    public List<StudentStatus> StudentStatusList { get; set; }
}
public class StudentStatus
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**My controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Student> model=new List<Student>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var student = new Student
        {
            Id = i.ToString(),
            FullName = "Asd" +i,
            StudentStatusList = new List<StudentStatus>
        {
            new StudentStatus{ID="1" , Type = "Present"},
            new StudentStatus{ID="2" , Type = "Absent"},
            new StudentStatus{ID="3" , Type = "Unrecorded"}
        }
        };
        model.Add(student);
    }

    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Student> model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //TODO: Save your model and redirect
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**The View**

```
@model List<Models.Student>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    <h2>Index</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().FullName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().StudentStatus)
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach (var status in item.StudentStatusList)
                        {
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.StudentStatus, status.ID, new { @id = "Status" + item.Id+ status.ID, @Name = item.Id })
                            @Html.Label("Status" + item.Id+ status.ID, status.Type)
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    }
```

After I run the application I found that the model is null and I don't know why

[image]

I appreciate any help.

**Edit**

I have also tried the following and the model still null

```
@model List<Models.Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().FullName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().StudentStatus)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].FullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var status in Model[i].StudentStatusList)
                    {
                        <label>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].StudentStatus, status.ID, new { id = "" })
                            <span>@status.Type</span>
                        </label>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**Edit 2**
the application after execute
[image]

**Edit 3**

Thanks [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) For your help I just restart my computer and every things work correctly

Comment: You need to change the outer `foreach` loop (iterating each `Student`) to a `for` loop or use a custom `EditorTemplate` as explained in the dupe.

Comment: You should also consider a view model containing `List<Student>` and `List<StudentStatus>` so you have only one copy of status list - `foreach (status in Model.StudentStatusList) { <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Students[i].StudentStatus, status.ID, new { id = "" })<span>@status.Type</span></label> }` And NEVER set the `Name` attribute when using the HtmlHelpers

Comment: Dear Stephen I change the view to   @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].FullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var status in Model[i].StudentStatusList)
                    {
                        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].StudentStatus, status.ID, new { id = "" })
                            <span>@status.Type</span>
</label>
                    }                </td>            </tr>        } and still get null

Comment: Too hard to read your code in comments (especially when its not formatted). Edit you question and append the revised view code to the bottom and I'll have a look.

Comment: Okay I edit the question

Comment: You cannot change the original question. I have rolled back the changes and **appended** the new code.

Comment: The revised code you have shown works fine. The `model` parameter will not be `null` (although the `FullName` property will be because you have not rendered a control for it

Comment: It doesn't work when click submit the revived model is null, I solve the problem if I use FormCollection instead of List<student> and I don't know why it doesn't work if use list?

Comment: Then you have done something else wrong that you have not shown us. But the image you have shown for the view does not match your code - the table headings would be displayed as "Full Name" and "Student Status" (not `"Student Name" and "Status") so I assume you have not shown the correct code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103777/discussion-between-abdul-hadi-and-stephen-muecke).