# populate radiobuttonlist from database table in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

[image]

I want to create a form like above,

also have to populate Viewer User Groups accodrding to **UserGroups** table
[image]

```
public partial class UserGroup
{
    public string UserGroup_ID { get; set; }
    public string UserGroupNameEn { get; set; }
}
```

So populate this user groups and get the filled data I created new model (so it can apply to view (1st image))

I followed theses Stack overflow [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768274/correct-way-to-bind-an-mvc3-radiobutton-to-a-model) and  [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638966/mvc-radiobutton-binding-complex-object) to make this

this is controller class for this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ProductFields_Create()
    {
        var model = new ProductFields
        {
            LisGroups = GetUserGroupListEn()
        };

        return View(model);

    }

    public MultiSelectList GetUserGroupListEn()
    {
        return new MultiSelectList(db.UserGroup.ToList(), "UserGroup_ID", "UserGroupNameEn");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ProductFields_Create(ProductFields product_fields)
    {
      ...........
    }
```

this is model class for first image

```
public class ProductFields
{
    public string ProductFieldID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public string ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldDiscriptionAr { get; set; }

    public List<UserGroup> LisGroups { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SelectedGroupID { get; set; }
}
```

viewpage for above view

```
@model Project_Name.Models.ProductFields

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <fieldset>
         <div class="form-horizontal">           

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            .....

             <div class="form-group">
             <div>
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedGroupID)
                 foreach (var group in Model.LisGroups)
                 {
                 <div>
                     @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedGroupID, group.UserGroup_ID, new { id = "emp" + group.UserGroup_ID })
                     @Html.Label("emp" + group.UserGroup_ID, employee.Label)
                 </div>
                 }

             </div>

          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
           </div>


        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

but here I'm getting major errors with red squiggly lines

> The name 'group' does not exist in the current context

[image]

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

[image]

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it is, Once I select Group A , it should pass Group As , ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a `MultiSelectList` (which is a class for use in the `ListBox()` and `ListBoxFor()` methods). And the reason for the error is that your property is `List<UserGroup> LisGroups` but your attempting to assign typeof `MultiSelectList` to it.

Change your GET method to

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductFields_Create()
{
    var model = new ProductFields
    {
        LisGroups = db.UserGroup.ToList();
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Side note: The property could be `public IEnumerable<UserGroup> LisGroups { get; set; }` and then delete the unnecessary use of `.ToList()`

Then in the view

```
@foreach (var group in Model.LisGroups)
{
    <div>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedGroupID, group.UserGroup_ID, new { id = "" })
            <span>@group.UserGroupNameEn</span>
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Im still getting `The name 'group' does not exist in the current context` error

Comment: Do you mean in the view?

Comment: yeah in the cshtml  view page , Im still getting this error with red squiqqly lines

Comment: Ahh got it , I've missed `@` sign in front of `foreach` now this is okay , thanks lot